# Most pythonic way to import custom helper functions into a main script?

Tags: python, directory-structure, readability

Let's say we have an app, `app.py`, that does a variety of things. Of course, along the way, there is bound to be "helper" functions that do things such as cleaning data, creating a visualization, doing currency conversion, etc etc. I've learned that storing these helper functions elsewhere is helpful in decluttering the main script, increasing readability. My question regards the most pythonic way to import these helper functions to the main script.

The way I've been doing it is the following:

```
app_dir
|
|
|----- helper_modules
|       |_ __init__.py
|       |_ module1.py
|       |_ module2.py
|       |_ module3.py
|
|----- app.py
```

And importing them the following way in `app.py`:

```
from helper_modules.module1 import _function(s)_
from helper_modules.module2 import _function(s)_
from helper_modules.module3 import _function(s)_
```

And everything works fine. However, I've seen source code that does it the following way ([example here](https://github.com/streamlit/example-app-commenting)):

```
app_dir
|
|
|----- utils
|       |_ module1.py
|       |_ module2.py
|       |_ module3.py
|
|----- app.py
```

And import the scripts the following way in `app.py`:

```
from utils import module1, module2, module3
```

Ultimately, my question is: What is the most pythonic way to import custom scripts into the main file? Do you want to turn the folder of helper functions into a module by including the `__init__.py` file or is just creating a utils folder fine? Also, instead of `helper_modules` in the first example, should it be renamed to `utils` (that is, is that a conventional naming rule)? I want to make sure my directory structure is as pythonic and readable as possible as others will be reading it.

Comment: The only answer is "it depends". Sometimes, it's more useful to import the module and access the functions as attributes of that module to make it clear where the functions are defined. Other times, the function name alone is sufficient to allow it to be imported directly.

Comment: IMO, it's often better to err on the side being explicit and importing the module rather than the function name.

Comment: So you're saying you prefer the first example, but without specifying the function name, as in `from helper_modules import module3` then in the main script utilizing the function with `module3.function(...)` @chepner?

Comment: Are you asking about the package name used? I don't consider that part of the question at all. The *second* example makes it clearer where `module1.foo` comes from compared to a bare name `foo` being added to the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways work, however to make later refactoring easier I use:

In `__init__.py`

```py
from helper_modules.module1 import myfunction

__all__ = ['myfunction']
```

In `app.py`

```py
from helper_modules import myfunction
```

This makes moving my_function to module2 later easier.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) for `__all__`.